# Прелоадер при отправке формы почему срабатывает только один раз?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот что имеем на js:

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

$('#uyt').on('click', function() {
    $('#loader').addClass('loader');
    //$('#loader').attr('id', 'loader');
    //$('.preloader').addClass('active');

    $('#uyt', function() {
        // Эмулируем долгий запрос
        sleep(7000).then(function() {
            $('#loader').removeClass('loader');
            $('#loader').removeAttr('id', 'loader');
            $('#myDiv').removeClass('myDiv');
            sleep(7000).then(function() {$('#myDiv').addClass('myDiv');});
        })
    })
});
```

Вот что имеем в HTML:

```
<section style="margin:0;">

<div id="loader"></div>

<div id="myDiv" class="myDiv">
    <br><br>
    <div id="notint" STYLE="text-align: center;"></div>
    <div id="response_result" style="text-align:center;"></div>
    <br><br>
</div>
```

Вот что имеем в CSS:

```
#response_result{
        text-align: center;
    }


    /* Center the loader */
    .loader {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
        border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
        animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
        0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
        100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }

    @keyframes spin {
        0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
        100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }

    /* Add animation to "page content" */
    .animate-bottom {
        position: relative;
        -webkit-animation-name: animatebottom;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
        animation-name: animatebottom;
        animation-duration: 1s
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes animatebottom {
        from { bottom:-100px; opacity:0 }
        to { bottom:0px; opacity:1 }
    }

    @keyframes animatebottom {
        from{ bottom:-100px; opacity:0 }
        to{ bottom:0; opacity:1 }
    }

    .myDiv {
        display: none;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Вообщем при 1 клике по кнопочке прелоадер срабатывает, но при последующих кликах запрос отправляется без прелоадера. Направьте на путь истинный)))

Comment: Вы удаляете аттрибут id    `$('#loader').removeAttr('id', 'loader');`

Comment: Спасибо, ваше замечание натолкнуло на правильное решение)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рабочий вариант JS для кода выше:

```
    function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}


$('#uyt').on('click', function() {
    $('#myDiv').addClass('myDiv');
    $('#loader').removeClass('myDiv');
    $('#loader').addClass('loader');


    $('#uyt', function() {
        // Эмулируем долгий запрос
        sleep(7000).then(function() {
            $('#loader').addClass('myDiv');
            $('#loader').removeClass('loader');
            $('#myDiv').removeClass('myDiv');

        })
    })
});
```